# Getting the old response in collectasstate

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, viewmodel, jetpack

```
var authViewModel: UserAuthViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val userData by authViewModel.authUserData.collectAsState()
```

I call api on a click

```
} else {
if (textUser.contains("@")) { // for email
sharedViewModel.addType(false)
sharedViewModel.addUsername(textUser)
navigation = true
authViewModel.getAuthUserDataEmail(textUser = textUser)
loading = true
userData
} else {
```

and at the bottom I handle the response like this

```
LaunchedEffect(userData,navigation) {
    if (userData != null && navigation) {
        when (userData?.result?.user_exist) {
            "USER_NOT_EXISTS" -> {
                navController.navigate(NavScreens.REGISTRATION.route)
            }
            "ACCOUNT_EXISTS" -> {
                navController.navigate(NavScreens.LOGIN.route)
            }
            "ACCOUNT_NOT_VERIFIED" -> {
                sharedViewModel.addOtpType("account_verification")
                navController.navigate(NavScreens.VERIFY_ACCOUNT.route)
            }
            else -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "${userData?.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        loading = false
        navigation = false
    }
}
```

This is my view model:

```
class UserAuthViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel()  {
val authUserData: StateFlow<AuthResponseModel?> get() = repository.authUserData

    fun getAuthUserData(textUser: String, countryCode:String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = repository.getAuthUserData(AuthUser(username = textUser, country_dial_code = countryCode))
        }
    }
    fun getAuthUserDataEmail(textUser: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            var result = repository.getAuthUserData(AuthUser(username = textUser))
            Log.d("TAG", "getAuthUserDataEmail: ${authUserData.value?.result?.user_exist}")
        }
    }
```

The problem is, let's say I type a registered user, so condition 1 is true and I go on login screen. Now let's say I come back and type an unregistered user so should be going to the register screen, but I go to the login screen.

This is now the problem of condition when I hit the api again it goes to the register screen that indicated I'm getting one old response which is causing it give unwanted results.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please learn how to format your code on stackoverflow. Unreadable code may get more downvotes than answers.

Answer (score 1):

so i solved this issue by clearing the response before i hit the api again

```
> fun clearAuthUserData() {
>         _authUser.value = null
>     }
```

and the calling it in the viewmodel like this

```
fun getAuthUserDataEmail(textUser: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.clearAuthUserData()
        var result = repository.getAuthUserData(AuthUser(username = textUser))
    }
}
```